# Exception Message: Some kind of disk I/O error occurred

Tags: sqlite, windows-xp, io

I am getting this error when I try to run a update query on a SQLite database. This only happens on XP (on Vista works fine). The database is created without any issue, insert also works fine. 
I also checked and I have permissions and disk space available (as sqlite.org says these are possible causes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One answer that has worked for me is to use the [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) statement to set the journal_mode value to something other than "DELETE". You do this by issuing a PRAGMA statement such as `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF` in the same way you would issue a query statement. I posted an example of this using c# at: http://www.stevemcarthur.co.uk/blog/post/some-kind-of-disk-io-error-occurred-sqlite/

Edit

Probably a better PRAGMA statement to issue is `PRAGMA journal_mode = TRUNCATE` rather than "OFF" as a couple of the others have suggested.

Comment: This looked like the perfect solution to what I was looking for, but it turns out that trying to execute this PRAGMA throws the same exception. :D

Answer (score 3):

Per http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode (emphasis mine):

> The OFF journaling mode disables the rollback journal completely. No rollback journal is ever created and hence there is never a rollback journal to delete. The OFF journaling mode disables the atomic commit and rollback capabilities of SQLite. The ROLLBACK command no longer works; it behaves in an undefined way. Applications must avoid using the ROLLBACK command when the journal mode is OFF. **If the application crashes in the middle of a transaction when the OFF journaling mode is set, then the database file will very likely go corrupt.**

Sounds like you are on the right track, but one of the other options would be safer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have .db-journal file next to database file? If so make sure your application can **delete** files from folder where database is located.

Your symptoms indicate that SQLite can read and write but is unable to delete journal file.

Comment: Wow, I think this is actually my problem... on Windows 10 under the WSL with a folder in dropbox, I think Windows is actually preventing SQLite from being able to access its own journal because dropbox has opened it for syncing!

Comment: This is exactly my situation. I paused Dropbox syncing and now I am writing tons to the database no problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be using the following SQL statement

```
"PRAGMA journal_mode = TRUNCATE"
```

It still keeps the journal, so if the power fails during a transaction you're still able to rollback and you'll avoid database corruption. The difference between `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` is that delete creates and deletes constantly the journal file for each statement.
Truncate only needs to create it once and just overwrites it. In my case it was a lot faster and I avoided the weird permissions that are coming with the standard `journal_mode = DELETE`.

Please refer to [SQlite3 Pragma_journal_mode explenation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode)