# Just started getting AIR SQLite Error 3182 Disk I/O error occurred

Tags: sqlite, air

We have a new beta version of our software with some changes, but not around our database layer.

We've just started getting Error 3128 reported in our server logs.  It seems that once it happens, it happens for as long as the app is open.  The part of the code where it is most apparent is where we log data every second via SQLite.  We've generated 47k errors on our server this month alone.

```
3128     Disk I/O error occurred.   Indicates that an operation could not be completed because of a disk I/O error. This can happen if the runtime is attempting to delete a temporary file and another program (such as a virus protection application) is holding a lock on the file. This can also happen if the runtime is attempting to write data to a file and the data can't be written.
```

I don't know what could be causing this error.  Maybe an anti-virus program?  Maybe our app is getting confused and writing data on top of each other?  We're using async connections.

It's causing lots of issues and we're at a loss.  It has happened in our older version, but maybe 100 times in a month rather than 47,000 times.  Either way I'd like to make it happen "0" times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make sure database delete, update, insert only happened one at at time by wrapping a little wrapper.  On top of that, we had to watch for error 3128 and retry.  I think this is because we have a trigger running that could lock the database after we inserted data.

Comment: what do you mean wrapping a little wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: [Exception Message: Some kind of disk I/O error occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979322/exception-message-some-kind-of-disk-i-o-error-occurred)

Summary: There is probably not a problem with the database but a problem creating (or deleting) the temporary file once the database is opened.  AIR may have permissions to the database, but not to create or delete files in the directory.

> One answer that has worked for me is to use the **`PRAGMA`** statement to set the **`journal_mode`** value to something other than **`DELETE`**. You do this by issuing a **`PRAGMA`** statement in the same way you would issue a query statement.

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF
```

Unfortunately, if the application crashes in the middle of a transaction when the OFF journaling mode is set, then the database file will very likely go corrupt.<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode