# sqlite windows unable to insert -

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, sqlite, adodb

I'm seeing an error trying to insert new records to q sqlite3 db via Classic ASP, where updates and reads work fine.

```
ODBC driver does not support the requested properties.
/engine/includes/ajaxed/class_database/database.asp, line 160
```

which basically boils down to your standard:

```
connectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & server.mappath("/site.db") & ";LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;
set connection = server.createObject("ADODB.connection")
connection.open(connectionString)
set aRS = server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' error raised on next line
aRS.open tablename, connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable
```

Permissions are correct (basically that file has everyone full control, including IUSR), and I've had to change the db to no journalling due to this problem ([Exception Message: Some kind of disk I/O error occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979322/exception-message-some-kind-of-disk-i-o-error-occurred)); reads and updates to existing records are fine.

I am using the current version of the http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ 32-bit odbc driver.

I've tried setting other recordset options like (adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic); no luck, same error message. I've attempted a read of the sqliteodbc code to see what the supported properties /are/, but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Your code (which worked for me when I tested it) does not match your objective. It's retrieving a table (provided `tablename` actually holds the name of a table). It doesn't insert anything. If you want to insert records, why don't you use an [ADO Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677502) object to run an `INSERT INTO` statement?

Comment: `Insert into table` does actually work. But having a recordset in which you would then issue something like `aRS.addNew() .. aRS.update,`, say within a loop, doesn't work. Basically I can't have a recordset that I can traverse as an active, connected recordset since I can't figure out the what the supported properties of an active recordset are.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with something that works rather than being hung up on something that doesn't. However, if you want to stick with the `aRS.Update` route, you need to show the code that fails (including error messages, etc.), i.e. what you're doing between `aRS.Open` and `aRS.Update`. We can't help you with code that's already working.

Comment: actually, I'm not yet doing anything between `aRS.open` at this stage, because the ODBC driver can't DO the `open` because of the error I mentioned... I use an active recordset when I need to return the newly inserted table key so it can be used for subsequent inserts (e.g. referenced tables), and `insert into` is a non-returning query.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
Const adOpenKeyset      = 1
Const adLockPessimistic = 2
Const adCmdTable        = 2

db = "C:\test.db"
connectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & db & _
  ";LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open connectionString
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

tablename = "a"
rs.Open tablename, conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

cols   = Array("id", "name")
values = Array(3, "baz")
rs.AddNew cols, values
rs.Update
```

Example:

```
C:\>sqlite3 test.db "CREATE TABLE a (id integer, name varchar(20));"

C:\>sqlite3 test.db "INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'foo');"

C:\>sqlite3 test.db "INSERT INTO a VALUES (2, 'bar');"

C:\>sqlite3 test.db "SELECT * FROM a;"
1|foo
2|bar

C:\>cscript //NoLogo C:\path\to\sample.vbs

C:\>sqlite3 test.db "SELECT * FROM a;"
1|foo
2|bar
3|baz
```

Comment: Having previously changed tack and gone with something else, I then came back to another problem and hit the problem again. A google search, and lo here's my unanswered question again. I came back to it and tried your approach and MY sqlite database throws `Provider error '8002000a' Out of present range.` so it looks like there's some difference in the drivers we are using - maybe 32/64 bit, or some dumb problem like that. Looks like I'll have to follow my nose and see how I got around it last time!

Comment: If you want help you need to show your code. Post a new question for this.