# Mavericks ruby on rails SQLite3 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, osx-mavericks

I already have an application on my local OS and I update the OS to Mavericks.
Something wrong happens! 
After I start rails s, the error is like: `SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error: PRAGMA table_info("users")`

By the way, I am using cancan in my local env.

Can somebody help me about that?

Comment: Have you tried checking the databases to see if they were corrupted? Maybe try opening them in something like  [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the users table exists?

Comment: Did you try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979322/exception-message-some-kind-of-disk-i-o-error-occurred ?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I upgraded to OSX Mavericks. My database appeared to be corrupted, with an error very similar to yours. Dropping and rebuilding solved the problem.

In Rails, easily accomplished with:

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`

or to combine the last 3:

`rake db:drop db:setup`

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, so this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.